# DNN SendGrid confuguration is NOT working

Tags: smtp, dotnetnuke, sendgrid, dnn9

I am using DNN 9.1 and I am trying to set the SMTP configuration by my SendGrid username and password, but this error always appears.
[image]

FYI, my old account was working properly but it stopped working suddenly, I created a new one and added it to the DNN and the same issue still appears, any suggestions?

**Edit**
I found this error log in the DNN admin logs portal

AbsoluteURL:/API/PersonaBar/ServerSettingsSmtpHost/SendTestEmail

DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke

ExceptionGUID:c3cbbedf-c450-4c50-82ad-3bc0f946d8fe

AssemblyVersion:

PortalId:-1

UserId:-1

TabId:-1

RawUrl:

Referrer:

UserAgent:

ExceptionHash:FbT04vCDY1wSj04IwamtapyPstw=

Message:Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

StackTrace:

at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 read, Boolean readLine) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean oneLine) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller) at System.Net.Mail.CheckCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String& response) at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
InnerMessage:

InnerStackTrace:

Source:System

FileName:

FileLineNumber:0

FileColumnNumber:0

Method:

Server Name: yoga-van-devweb1

Answer (score 1):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

You say that you configured your SMTP settings with your username and password, however SendGrid recently changed the requirements for this. Usernames and passwords are no longer accepted and you should use an API Key instead.

Check the documentation for [using a SendGrid API Key with SMTP here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/upgrade-your-authentication-method-to-api-keys/#upgrade-to-api-keys-for-your-smtp-integration).

Briefly, instead of your username and password, you should use the username `apikey` and the password should be an API Key you generate with mail send permissions.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: If that's really the cause for this error, you guys should reword your error message.

Comment: I don't think we have control over the ultimate error message you are seeing in your UI here. Your system is indeed "Unable to read data from the transport connection" but the reason that the connection closed is obscured. Hopefully this does fix your problem though.